# Accounting treatment for small bank verification deposits?

Tags: accounting

How do I record small deposits (e.g. $0.05, $0.07) as a result of bank verification for purposes of accounting? As income? Negative expenses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they don't withdraw it back (some institutions do), then you can write it down as income. Categorizing it as "interest income" seems the closest fit to me.

Comment: Adding update: I opened an account last year, and the verification amounts weren't withdrawn. They ended up being added to my 1099-INT from that institution, so I guess the banks treat it as interest as well.

Comment: If they do pull it back out, call the withdrawl interest paid. Of course the fact is that these small amounts make no practical difference, but.

Comment: If they pull it back out then there's no income and no expense. It's a reversed transaction.